# Inserir dados de uma tabela em outra comparando ID

Tags: php, mysql

No meu sistema tenho duas tabelas, uma com cadastros de usuários, obviamente, cada um possui seu ID.

E outra tabela onde são colocados os dados de envio de presentes de um usuário para outro, porém só aparecem os IDs de quem envia e quem recebe.

Eu acrescentei mais duas colunas na tabela de presentes que seriam para os nomes e username dos usuários que receberam o presente, assim eu sabia quem recebeu por nome e não por ID.

Minha ideia seria atualizar/inserir os nomes e usernames comparando o ID de quem recebeu com o ID da tabela de usuários.

Só para constar, comprei o sistema pronto e quis implementar, já busquei de todo jeito substituir para que os nomes já fossem para tabela, mas nada feito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seu conceito esta errado, você não precisa duplicar dados na sua base de dados. Para você recuperar o nome do usuário que deu o presente é só fazer um `INNER JOIN`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT a.id, userDoador.nome AS nome_doador, userReceptor AS nome_receptor FROM Presentes a
INNER JOIN Usuarios userDoador ON a.id_user_doador = userDoador.id
INNER JOIN Usuarios userReceptor ON a.id_user_receptor = userReceptor.id;
```

Desta forma você não precisa dos campos adicionais na tabela `Presentes`, de quebra, assim que atualizar o nome do usuário, automaticamente afetara o resultado deste `SELECT`.

[Veja mais sobre `INNER JOIN`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp)

Comment: Amigão, eu não consegui por esse jeito, mas só de ter me apresentado a função busquei outra forma e consegui.

`SELECT users.fullname, users.login, gifts.giftId, gifts.status, gifts.id
FROM users
INNER JOIN gifts ON users.id = gifts.giftTo`

Comment: Mas a ideia era essa mesmo, só usei nomes genéricos porque não sabia os nomes reais das suas tabelas.